# Appropriate submit function for multiple textboxes

Tags: python, matplotlib, textbox

I am making a Matplotlib [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCEuB.png) where I want to interactively rescale the x and y axis. For this I want to use four textboxes where I can set the minimum and maximum of the x and y axis limits respectively. The code I have up until now is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,3,2])

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
gs.update(left=0.4, right=0.7, bottom=0.15, top=0.25, hspace=0.1)

axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j]) for i,j in [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]]
# create the textboxes
tb_xmin = TextBox(axes[0],'x', hovercolor='0.975', label_pad=0.1)
tb_xmax = TextBox(axes[1],'',  hovercolor='0.975')
tb_ymin = TextBox(axes[2],'y', hovercolor='0.975', label_pad=0.1)
tb_ymax = TextBox(axes[3],'',  hovercolor='0.975')

def submit(val):
    data = eval(val)
    # how to know which limit to set here?
    ax.set_xlim(data)
    plt.draw()

for tb in [tb_xmin,tb_xmax,tb_ymin,tb_ymax]:
    tb.on_submit(submit)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However I am stuck with the `submit` function. I want to have a function which recognises which textbox submits and input and sets the appropriate minimum or maximum value under the condition that the input is valid and within the datarange.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to update the limits via the TextBox inputs, you may pass some arguments together with the values to the function. A way to do this would be to create a lambda function, which has those arguments preset, depending on which limit to update.

```
def submit(val,func,pos):
    data = float(val)    
    func([data,None][::pos])

tb_xmin.on_submit(lambda val: submit(val, ax.set_xlim, 1))
tb_xmax.on_submit(lambda val: submit(val, ax.set_xlim, -1))
tb_ymin.on_submit(lambda val: submit(val, ax.set_ylim, 1))
tb_ymax.on_submit(lambda val: submit(val, ax.set_ylim, -1))
```

Another option would be to always call the same function on submit and let the function gather the values from all 4 TextBoxes and set the limits simulataneously.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,3,2])

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
gs.update(left=0.4, right=0.7, bottom=0.15, top=0.25, hspace=0.1)

axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j]) for i,j in [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]]
# create the textboxes
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
tb_xmin = TextBox(axes[0],'x', initial = str(xlim[0]), hovercolor='0.975', label_pad=0.1)
tb_xmax = TextBox(axes[1],'',  initial = str(xlim[1]), hovercolor='0.975')
tb_ymin = TextBox(axes[2],'y', initial = str(ylim[0]), hovercolor='0.975', label_pad=0.1)
tb_ymax = TextBox(axes[3],'',  initial = str(ylim[1]), hovercolor='0.975')

def submit(val):
    lim = [float(tb.text) for tb in [tb_xmin,tb_xmax,tb_ymin,tb_ymax]]
    ax.axis(lim)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

for tb in [tb_xmin,tb_xmax,tb_ymin,tb_ymax]:
    tb.on_submit(submit)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have posted this as a seperate question aswell: I noticed that adding a TextBox widget to matplotlib makes the interaction slower then when using no TextBox. Is this a general side issue of the TextBox widget?